# WSDL xsd import from https to http:443 when deployed

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl

I have a legacy SOAP WS in my JAVA project (1.7) which is currently giving some trouble. In its WEB-INF/wsdl/*.wsdl file there is this block

```
<xsd:schema>
  <xsd:import namespace="https://myUrl.com/" schemaLocation="myService_schema.xsd"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

right after its deployment, when i download its wsdl via wget I get the following

```
<xsd:schema xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="https://o2o-staging.beeweeb.com/" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" xmlns:wsp1_2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:import namespace="https://myUrl.com/" schemaLocation="http://myUrl.com:443/service-ws/myService?xsd=myService_schema.xsd"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

as you can see the xsd import address https://myUrl.com becomes http://myUrl.com:443, thus making the service inaccessible as nginx complains with a 400 error: The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port

I really did some searching and found no problem assimilated to this. Can somebody please explain to me what is going on, and how to possibly fix it? the namespace url https: //myUrl.com should really remain that way, and is it possible to avoi its becoming http: //myUrl.com:443 ?
My server is Jboss 7.1

Answer (score 0):

For whom it might be helpful.

When a soap webservice is deployed, jboss re-processes whatever wsdl and xsd you have in your WEB-INF/wsdl. My problem was that in my standalone.xml I had an http connector, while I actually needed an https one.

so you need to

1) change your connector to https (or whatever it is you are yousing for your web-app

```
<connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" socket-binding="http" 
 secure="true" proxy-port="443"/>
```

2) add and explicit wsdl port in your standalone.xml

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:webservices:1.2">
<modify-wsdl-address>true</modify-wsdl-address>
<wsdl-host>jbossws.undefined.host</wsdl-host>
<wsdl-port>443</wsdl-port>
```